# how print file content to stdout in vxWorks?

Tags: stdout, vxworks

I'm using putty to telnet a robot controller.
I need an equivalent of  the "cat" command in vxWorks, or some workaround to print the content of a text file to stdout.
how can i do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The copy function is overloaded to handle this. Call it with only one filename argument and stdout will be assumed as the second argument, e.g.:

```
-> copy "foo.txt"
bar
->
```

http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/vxworks/ref/usrFsLib.html#copy